# Non-visible Fraunhofer lines

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, spectroscopy

Fraunhofer lines are always displayed for the visible light, are there cases of Fraunhofer lines for non-visible range of electromagnetic range?

Googling non-visible Fraunhofer lines did not get me any related results, hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fraunhofer was using visible light from the sun to do his experiments - hence, the lines that he found were all in the visible spectrum. Of course, you are right that other absorption lines are present in the non-visible range of the spectrum - those ones just weren't officially recorded as being observed by Fraunhofer.

Comment: Is there a name for absorption lines present in the non-visible range?

Comment: Some of the lines in the Balmer series, Lyman series, etc. Also characteristic X-rays. You could look into specific parts of the spectrum by looking into that kind of spectroscopy - eg "microwave spectroscopy."